# Injecting Akka's TestProbe in place of child actors

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, probe

I have a parent actor named "manager" which creates several child actors.
These child actors then send back their response via "sender tell", i.e directly back to "manager".

I want to create a unit test for this manager actor, and therefore need to inject a probe to forward the messages from the manager to its children.

I used the following post: 
http://www.superloopy.io/articles/2013/injecting-akka-testprobe.html

However i'm still having some trouble getting this done correctly.

In order to simplify the situation, attached is code describing the actors and unit test i wrote for just one child.

Manager class:

```
trait ManagerChildProvider {
  def createTimestampPointChild: Actor
}

trait ProductionManagerChildProvider extends ManagerChildProvider {
  def createTimestampPointChild = new TimeDifferenceCalculationActor 
}

object Manager {
  def apply() = new Manager("cid1") with ProductionManagerChildProvider
}

class Manager(name: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  this: ManagerChildProvider =>

  @Autowired private val modelParams = new ModelParams //list of  parameters

  val timeDifference = context.actorOf(Props(createTimestampPointChild))

  def receive = {
    case p@TimePoint(tPoint) =>
      timeDifference ! p
    case _ =>
      log.error("Unknown message type")
  }
}
```

Child class:

```
class TimeDifferenceCalculationActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var previousTimestamp: Long = -1

  def receive = {
    case tPoint(timestamp) =>
          if (previousTimestamp != -1) {
            sender ! Result(1)
          }
    case _ =>
      log.error("Unknown message type")
  }
}
```

Test class:

```
object BarSpec {
  class Wrapper(target: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case x => target forward x
    }
  }
}

trait ChildrenProvider {
  def newFoo: Actor
}

class BarSpec extends TestKitSpec("BarSpec") {

  import Manager._
  import BarSpec._

trait TestCase {
    val probe = TestProbe()

    trait TestChildrenProvider extends ManagerChildProvider {
      def newBar = new Wrapper(probe.ref)
    }

    val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new Manager(componentId = "cid1") with TestChildrenProvider))
  }

  "Bar" should {
    "involve child in doing something" in new TestCase {

      actor ! tPoint(1)
      actor ! tPoint(2)

      probe.expectMsg(tPoint(1))
  //probe.reply("ReplyFromChild")
  //expectMsg("ReplyFromParent")
    }
  }
}
```

Additional test class:

```
abstract class TestKitSpec(name: String) extends TestKit(ActorSystem(name)) with MustMatchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike{

override def afterAll() {
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Currently i get the following errors:

> Error:(36, 42) object creation impossible, since method > createTimestampPointChild in trait ManagerChildProvider of > type => akka.actor.Actor is not defined
>       val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new Manager(componentId = "cid1") with TestChildrenProvider))
>
> Error:(11, 16) overriding method run in trait BeforeAndAfterAll of type > (testName: Option[String], args: > org.scalatest.Args)org.scalatest.Status;
>    method run in trait WordSpecLike of type (testName: Option[String], > args: org.scalatest.Args)org.scalatest.Status needs `abstract override' > modifiers
>   abstract class TestKitSpec(name: String) extends > TestKit(ActorSystem(name))

any help with these specific errors or with the task in general would be highly appreciated

Comment: How SensorHealthManagerChildProvider trait is defined?

Comment: I'm sorry, i mixed up the names a little bit. I renamed "SensorHealthManager" to "Manager", hence the confusion. I currently updated the code snips to include the name Manager. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The first error is because your trait `TestChildrenProvider` does not provide an implementation of the (abstract) method `createTimestampPointChild` from the trait `ManagerChildProvider` which it extends.